# Read a binary file where every element is a 2 byte integer

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have a binary file with the .b16 extension on it, the information contained is as unsigned integer (range 0..65535, file extension .b16, byte order: low-byte/high-byte).

Main files are otypes03.b08 to otypes08.b08, otypes09.b16 and
     otypes10.b16. They contain the coordinates of all inequivalent
     point sets (order types) for the given number n of points.

I've succesfully read all the files with .b08 extension, however when it comes to read the .b16 files I don't get the expected information.

What I have so far: (This is a modified version of the reading algorithm exclusively to be used for the .b16 format)

```
int readPoints(int n, string file_name, vector<Point> & vPoints){
    ifstream input(file_name, std::ios::binary);
    if(input.fail()) return 1;

    vector< unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});
    //Copying each pair of binary points to a vector of Point objects
    Point temp;
    for( unsigned int i=0;i< buffer.size();i+=4){
        temp.x = buffer[i] | buffer[i+1]  ;
        temp.y = buffer[i+2] | buffer[i+3]  ;
        vPoints.push_back(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Every element of the file is a coordinate of a point in the plane, however it seems that I'm reading wrong, the coordinates read are not the ones that should be. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

What I use for the .b08 format:

```
//Reads a file of binary points and stores it on vector vPoints.
int readPoints(int n, string file_name, vector<Point> & vPoints){
    ifstream input(file_name, std::ios::binary);
    if(input.fail()) return 1;
    // copies all data into buffer
    //Stored as unsigned int. Arithmetic operations (+-*/) can be used! :)
    //Can be treated as signed int or unsigned int.
    vector< unsigned char> buffer(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input), {});
    //Copying each pair of binary points to a vector of Point objects
    Point temp;
    cout << "Buffer size: " << buffer.size() << endl;
    for( unsigned int i=0;i< buffer.size();i+=2){
        temp.x = buffer[i];
        temp.y = buffer[i+2];
        vPoints.push_back(temp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More information on the database I'm using is here:
http://www.ist.tugraz.at/aichholzer/research/rp/triangulations/ordertypes/

The file I'm trying to read is otypes09.b16 which is 5.7MB just in case you want to try it out.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You have two options:  1) Read the 16-bit file into memory, then swap bytes as necessary; or 2) Read two bytes at a time, assemble into the correct Endianess and store into memory.

Comment: Is it possible that the byte order is different from that of your system? If so, you should swap the order of the bytes as you are reading the file

Comment: BTW, if the byte ordering of the file is the same as your system, read in the data as 16-bit, no conversions necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for( unsigned int i=0;i< buffer.size();i+=4){
    temp.x = buffer[i] | buffer[i+1]  ;
    temp.y = buffer[i+2] | buffer[i+3]  ;
    vPoints.push_back(temp);
}
```

The above is incorrect -- you're OR-ing the bits of the upper 8 bits on top of the lower 8 bits, which corrupts the data.  You need to shift the bits first (which bits you need to shift will depend on whether the file stores its 16-bit words in big-endian format or little-endian format).

If the file's data is in little-endian format, this should work:

```
// read in little-endian 16-bit words
for( unsigned int i=0;i< buffer.size();i+=4){
    temp.x = ((unsigned short)buffer[i+0]) | (((unsigned short)buffer[i+1])<<8);
    temp.y = ((unsigned short)buffer[i+2]) | (((unsigned short)buffer[i+3])<<8);
    vPoints.push_back(temp);
}
```

... or if the file's data is stored in big-endian format, it would be more like this:

```
// read in big-endian 16-bit words
for( unsigned int i=0;i< buffer.size();i+=4){
    temp.x = (((unsigned short)buffer[i+0])<<8) | ((unsigned short)buffer[i+1]);
    temp.y = (((unsigned short)buffer[i+2])<<8) | ((unsigned short)buffer[i+3]);
    vPoints.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: The parenthetical at the end of the question suggests the file is little-endian, so it would probably be clearer to emphasize the little-endian case by putting it first.

Comment: This works, however, the values I get are really big, I don't know if this is ok or if I have to shift back 8 bits again when processing them. The values displayed actually have the correct shape for every order type, it's just they're too big and it makes me doubt. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Unsigned 16-bit integers can hold values from 0-65535; in that way they are different from unsigned 8-bit integers which can only hold values from 0-255.  I suspect that the larger values is the expected behavior (because being able to hold larger values is the only advantage of using 16-bit instead of 8-bit coding, otherwise, why waste disk space making your file twice as big?)

Comment: And it makes sense to just do the operations I'm trying to with that data, thanks! Marking this answer as final.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
uint8_t lsb;
uint8_t msb;
uint16_t value;
std::vector<uint16_t> database;
//...
input.read((char *) &lsb, sizeof(lsb));
input.read((char *) &msb, sizeof(msb));
value = msb * 256 + lsb;
database.push_back(value);
```

Since this is a *binary* file, the `read` method is used.
You could replace the `value` assignment with:
`value = msb << 8 | lsb;`
Although a good compiler should translate the first `value` assignment into the second.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, depending on meanimg of the data, and having absolute resolution I like to uses unions. What you could do is have a union that has an int member as well as a struct containing 2 shorts. Each short will hold the binary structure of the 2 16 bit ints.

Having said that, the above answers may do just fine for you. Many ways of doing things like this, so design the right api for you!